# How to edit cells in excel while vba script is running continously

Tags: excel, vba

```
Option Explicit
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" _
(ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Dim status As String


Sub StartModule()

    Dim index As Integer
    Dim result As String
    Dim o: Set o = CreateObject("NAddIn.Functions")
    status = ""
    Do Until status = "DADA"
        result = o.getRandomNumber
        Range("F2").Value = result
        Sleep123
        If status = "EXIT" Then Exit Do
    Loop
End Sub

Sub StopModule()
    status = "EXIT"
End Sub


Sub Sleep123()
    Sleep 1000 'Implements a 1 second delay
End Sub
```

This vba script is calling called `getRandomNumber()` which is a user defined function in dll file. After running by clicking start button, I am able to run the function which continuously generates a random number and shows in a cell .

The problem is I'm unable to click stop button or edit any cell and even I cannot close the xl file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `Sleep` API. The Sleep function not only suspends the execution of the current thread for a specified interval but also will not let you do anything else. i.e it will freeze Excel. Use this custom function `Wait` that I created many years ago.

```
Option Explicit

Dim status As String

Sub StartModule()
    Dim index As Integer
    Dim result As String

    Dim o: Set o = CreateObject("NAddIn.Functions")
    status = ""

    Do Until status = "DADA"
        result = o.getRandomNumber
        Range("F2").Value = result
        Wait 1 '<~~ Wait for a second
        If status = "EXIT" Then Exit Do
    Loop
End Sub

Sub StopModule()
    status = "EXIT"
End Sub

Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

BTW, it's not a good idea editing cells when you have set a timer to 1 second. When you are in the edit mode, you will get an error as Excel will not be able to write to cell F2. Consider increasing the timer in such a case :)